# How to install pygame in Windows 10 for python 3.9?

Tags: python, pygame

I have tried everything
Here are some of the methods I have tried

1. `C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39> python -m pip install pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl`

The following error is prompted:

```
ERROR: pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

2. `C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39> pip install pygame`

The following error is prompted:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\win 10\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\win 10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l782i464\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\win 10\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-l782i464\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-1zl98t9z'
         cwd: C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l782i464\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):

    **WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l782i464\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l782i464\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l782i464\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\win 10\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l782i464\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many packages do not have pre-built wheels for Python 3.9 as it is new.

Also pygame-1.9.6-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl is for Python 2.7

Your best bet is to revert to Python 3.8.6 to install pre-built wheel with pip

Answer (score 7):

You could use the pre-release version that supports Python 3.9.0.

```
python3 -m pip install pygame --pre --user
```

Comment: This should have been marked as the correct answer, since it actually poses a solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: i asked the question two to three weeks ago

Answer (score 1):

install pywin32 first ,pip install pywin32.
and then istall pygame pip install pygame
by doing this you shall be able to download it

Answer (score 1):

This is the way i did it.

Open command prompt on windows and type:

```
py -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

Then afterwards to test it out try this small game:

```
py -m pygame.examples.aliens
```

Answer (score 0):

With reference to @ViaxCo [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64462792/4520376) at above for pre-release version installation, which could be for Linux/ macOS, below is another option for Windows, in case 'python3' causing *"python was not found error"*. My installed python version is 3.9.6

```
python -m pip install pygame --pre --user
```