# How do I properly install the latest version of pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having trouble using the pygame module in my code. I installed pygame using the command `py -3 -m pip install pygame --user` and it said it was successful. However, when running my code, I get this error `No module named 'pygame'` in the Python idle 3.9.0.

Comment: Can you share the output of the following command?
`py-3 -m site`
This is to list the site packages directories. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122327/how-do-i-find-the-location-of-my-python-site-packages-directory

Comment: Actually the following should be enough to check: `py-3 -c "import site; print(site.ENABLE_USER_SITE)"`. User site packages might be disabled in your environment. Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/site.html#site.ENABLE_USER_SITE

Comment: sys.path = [...
   USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
(the character count was to long so I had to cut off the path)

Comment: I suggest trying to create `USER_SITE` directory by hand, then trying `pip install --user ...` again.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: `py-3 -c "from pathlib import Path; import site; Path(site.USER_SITE).mkdir(parents=True)"`

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to be using Python 3.9. It's very new so there may still be libraries and dependencies that don't work cleanly. Not sure if the situation has changed for pygame but [just over a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305748/how-to-install-pygame-in-windows-10-for-python-3-9), reverting to Python 3.8 was the answer.

Comment: Ill try that, thanks for the advice. EDIT: it worked! appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to download it using pip, by running the following command:

```
pip install pygame
```

or with pip3:

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Comment: @ZekeBek - Neither worked *how*?  Nothing at all happened? An error message was returned? You PC caught fire? Your cat ran away?  Help people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

just a simple command
`python -m pip install pygame`
or
`python3 -m pip install pygame`

Comment: I get no response from command prompt, it just brings me back to C:\Users\username>_

Answer (score 0):

`pip install pygame -U`

This should upgrade your pygame to the newest version.

Comment: I get this error when I try that " 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."